# Section and Surjectivity

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Let $f:A \to B$ be a function of sets. If $f$ has a section, $s:B\to A$, satisfying by definition $f\circ s=\text{id}_B$, then it is straightforward to show that $f$ is an epimorphism (i.e. surjective). My question is simple, is the opposite true?

Given an epimorphism $f:A\to B$, does there exists a section for it?

Comment: In the category of sets, the existence of right-inverses (or sections in your terminology) for all surjective functions is equivalent to the axiom of choice (AC).

Comment: This is really strange to use the langage of category if you are using only the set. Why not call it a surjection ? 
As Rob Arthan said, this is equivalent in AC and can be false in other category (e.g the category of rings).